# how to find the usage time of the android application?

Tags: android

I am trying to get the usage time of the application. I can able to get the application start time through logcat file but not able to get the application end time. How to get the application end time?

Any other approach to find the start and end time of the application

Thanks in advance.
Pushpa

Comment: There is no "application end time" in Android, any more than there is "application end time" on the server side of a Web app.